# An animal related question

Tags: riddle, science, animals

Here is an animal related question. It can be an animal or a riddle. Please give answer if you know and give necessary explanation.

> Which animal is 6-months male and 6-months female?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Are you sure this is not a trivia on zoology?

Comment: Is a *sea horse* an animal :-)?

Comment: Yes. **sea horse** is an animal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a puzzle.

Comment: I spent half an hour going through names of animals, young or otherwise, male and female, and there are so many of those that I'm still not at all convinced that this isn't a perfectly reasonable riddle.

Comment: @ABcDexter I see no reason to assume this is not a puzzle; it absolutely could be one, and closing because it might not be is presumptuous. @$\!$user45856 Without ruling out the cases mentioned in the current answers, this risks being *too broad*—the riddle itself does not seem to exclude those possibilities, and it should, or such answers would seem to fit the riddle at least as well as whatever answer you actually had in mind. I suggest you adjust the puzzle so such answers clearly don't fit, or this will likely be closed.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "*A rough estimate of the number of hermaphroditic animal species is 65,000*" you should put it in your question that it's not a hermaphrodite. 65,000 possible answers is *probably* too broad :P Even being more precise with "Sequential hermaphroditism" there are likely a lot of possible animals

Comment: "Molly the hermaphrodite dog" is another possibility. I think it needs more clues and some confirmations now after 16 hours. This could be a lot of legitimate things.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be this:

> The 12 signs of the Zodiac (greek: "Animal Cycle") are divided into male and female signs, 6 months worth of each.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the animal we are talking about is

> Doctor Who.

The last six months:

> [image: Capaldi]

The next six months:

> [image: Whittaker]

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> [Hermaphrodites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphrodite)?

6-months male and 6-months female

> can be construed to mean animals which can be male for half the time and female for half the time, i.e. have an equal probabilty of being male and female.

Comment: No, not a good answer.

Comment: @user45856 It would be hlpful if you could let know why this not a good answer.. posting a hint will help all in solving the puzzle..

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a:

> **Clown fish (Anemonefish)** because "Anemonefish are sequential hermaphrodites, meaning they develop into males first, and when they mature, they become females." [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphiprioninae) is an article about them. They can be male for six months and then female for six months due to environmental changes.